# How to select span element inside multiple div classes and id's?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I always wondered how can you select an element that is deeply buried in other elements that have classes and id's ?

For example :

```
<div class="container" id="footer">
        <div class="sixteen columns"><span>some text here</span>
```

If I want to select  element then what I would do is write in CSS the following :

```
.container #footer .sixteen .columns span {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Unfortunately it seems that this method is not valid or recognized by browsers.
Let's say that I don't want to give any general styles to 'sixteen columns' class or span itself. I just want to apply very specific styles to this very specific element.

How should I select that span element ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your code:

```
<div class="container" id="footer">
    <div class="sixteen columns"><span>some text here</span>
</div><!-- I've chosen to close the opened div element -->
```

Your selector *cannot* work, but it is definitely "*recognized by browsers*." The problem is that it is not, as you say, 'valid' (for the HTML structure that you have).

The problem is that, in CSS, white-space implies an ancestor-descendant relationship, so:

```
E F
```

Selects an element, matching selector `F`, that is a descendant of selector `E`; your own selector:

```
.container #footer .sixteen .columns span
```

selects a `<span>` element, within an element of class `'columns'`, within an element of class `'sixteen'`, within an element of `id="footer"` itself within an element of class `'container'`; giving HTML:

```
<element class="container">
    <element id="footer">
        <element class="sixteen">
            <element class="columns">
                <span></span>
            </element>
    </element>
</element>
```

Which bears no resemblance to your own HTML. As white-space establishes an ancestor-descendant relationship, the corollary is that *no white-space* implies the same element, which is what you were aiming for, I think. Omitting the white-space, then, gives the following selector:

```
#footer.container .sixteen.columns span {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

This selector is, probably, overly complex (given that an `id` uniquely identifies an element<sup>1</sup>), and could be re-written as simply:

```
#footer .sixteen.columns span {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

Or even, if you're willing, and able, to sacrifice some specificity:

```
#footer span {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

---

1. Note that a class-name is often used in JavaScript to denote a state, state-change or interaction of some kind; so it's not definitively redundant to combine an `id` with a `class` (`#footer.container`), but if the class is not dynamically added or removed, it probably is redundant and unnecessary. As with all things in web-development, it's worth experimenting to find out what works for you; contemporary browsers are fast enough for the most part, that adding a class-name to the selector isn't going to slow things down substantially, but beware of time-critical use-cases, when it's best to remove *everything* that's not absolutely necessary.

References:

- [CSS Selectors (and combinators)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Comment: Thank you for your broad answer !

Comment: One answer to rule them all.

Answer (score 3):

with:

```css
#footer > .sixteen.columns > span
```

Your selector does not work because you have spaces between selectors which refer to the same element.

e.g. `.container #footer`

But the space reads: "find an element with the id `footer` that is a [descendant](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) of an element with a class that is `container`". But you mean: "find an element that has the class `container` **AND** the id `footer`" which you can do by concatenating them without a space:

e.g. `.container#footer`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: Exactly, the > stand for direct child, thus should be a liiiitttleebit faster than the space :)

Comment: @Danny_Student Lets call it only "child" as there's no such `indirect child`. Technically, `>` is direct descendant combinator.

Comment: @HashemQolami is right, the "direct childs" are called childs and the "inderect ones" are called descendants.

Comment: @Danny_Student Have a look at: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

Comment: @NickRussler Do you have maybe any favorite one for learning purposes?

Comment: @Danny_Student IMHO the Mozilla Developer Network always makes a good comprise between coverage, accuracy and simplicity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain me things ! Wish you all a very nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange your selector like this

```css
#footer.container .sixteen.columns span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="footer">
  <div class="sixteen columns">
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `.container` should be omitted: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#Type_Selectors

Comment: That depends if the `container` class is used to designate that an event has happened, or not; or any other state has changed, or not-yet changed.

Comment: Yup, but most likely `container` is no such class, anyways a link to a rather good coding guideline never hurts ;)

Comment: Possibly not, but it does no, or insignificant, harm when included. Even unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks guys for some explanations !

Answer (score -1):

```css
#footer span { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: The `<span>` is an element, not a class-name.

Comment: It should be #footer span

Comment: Ok, ok. You are the best. :)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.