# Select span tag nested inside multiple div blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i select this specific span tag and change the color of the text to white, without using id's? This is the friend section on the page [younow](http://www.younow.com), i try to inject a code to change the css of the page, so i am not able to add any id's..

```
<div id="leftsidebar">
    <div class="channel-menu-content">
        <div class="left-panel">
            <div class="panel-title nowrap short-text" ng-if="leftSidebar.session.user.userId !== 0" ng-click="leftSidebar.friendsCollapsed  = !leftSidebar.friendsCollapsed">
                <span translate="sidebar_online_friends">Freunde</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344015/4684797), and tried it like this:

```
        $("div#leftsidebar .channel-menu-content.left-panel.panel-title span").css("color","white");
        $("div#leftsidebar .channel-menu-content.left-panel.nowrap span").css("color","white");
        $("div#leftsidebar .channel-menu-content.left-panel.short-text span").css("color","white");
```

But no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have spaces between class names

```
$('#leftsidebar .channel-menu-content .left-panel .panel-title span')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute equals selector

```
$("span[translate=sidebar_online_friends]").css("color", "white")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Jquery is loaded in the page you can select the span element using:

```
$("span[translate='sidebar_online_friends']")
```

you could then change the colour by doing:

```
$("span[translate='sidebar_online_friends']").css("color","#FFF")
```

Comment: Yep i was pretty slow.